# как сделать блоки как на картинке с с помощью flex-box или grid-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Добрый день как можно сверстать блоки как на этой картине ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если эту картинку текстом описать, полезнее вопрос не станет.

Comment: @teran, по тексту «блоки как на картинке» этот вопрос, конечно, можно отыскать. но тот, кто в будущем будет разыскивать ответы на **свой** схожий вопрос, вряд ли будет искать эти ответы по такому запросу.

Comment: @Sevastopol', прекрасная позиция, полностью её разделяю. вот об этом и речь: о помощи тем, у кого возникнет такая же проблема, как у автора вопроса. как они смогут найти ответ? по ключевым словам «блоки как на картинке»? думаю, нереально. скорее всего, будут искать немного другой текст. если бы я владел терминологией данной предметной области, я бы с радостью сам добавил нужные слова в вопрос. и не писал бы призывы к этому (и не получал бы в ответ непонимание и недоверие). а так приходится писать призывы, пытаться объяснить бросающимся мне возражать, в общем, вот это всё…

Comment: @Sevastopol', вот смотрите: автор вопроса уже получил ответ. вряд ли он заинтересован в том, чтобы его вопрос ещё кому-нибудь помог, но: этот вопрос просмотрели как минимум три человека, явно владеющие нужной терминологией (вы и два оставивших ответы). вот если бы кто-то из вас троих уделил пару минут своего времени, и дополнил текст вопроса словами, благодаря которым ответы на этот вопрос смогут быть найдены теми, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, было бы просто замечательно. // продолжение в следующем комментарии.

Comment: продолжение: а если таких желающих помочь не найдётся, то вопрос канет в лету, и если вдруг кто-то захочет написать на него ещё один ответ, то его труд будет напрасен: автор вопроса ответ уже получил, а другие, кому можно было бы помочь, не найдут этот вопрос из-за отсутствия в нём текстового описания проблемы. вот потому и вполне логично закрывать «плохие» (плохо-находимые) вопросы: чтобы желающие дать дополнительные ответы не тратили время впустую. с надеждой, что они найдут какой-нибудь другой, «лучший» вопрос, на который и дадут ответ, с пользой для
тех, кому такой ответ нужен.

Comment: @Sevastopol', даже вопрос из пары десятков знаков может быть хорошим. и вряд ли стоит полагаться на то, что автор вопроса владеет нужной терминологией. тут как раз могли бы помочь отвечающие: и нужной терминологией они владеют, и плюшки за правку вопроса им полагаются. а закрывать «плохие» вопросы — это же тоже помощь: это сигнал желающим ответить — «вопрос плохой, не стоит на него тратить время, но если очень хотите, то внесите сначала правку в этот вопрос, чтобы он стал полезным».

Comment: @Sevastopol', для вас это, наверно, прозвучит смешно, но я действительно не смогу сформулировать, что же на самом деле требуется автору вопроса. ещё раз повторюсь: **если бы мог**, то так и сделал бы. в вопросах, касающихся знакомых мне областей знания я это проделывал неоднократно. // можете трактовать мой голос за закрытие как мягкий призыв к отвечающим (автору вопроса призыв вряд ли интересен — ответ он уже получил): «пожалуйста, сделайте этот вопрос полезным для многих других! (а не только для автора вопроса)»

Comment: @Sevastopol', я действительно не смогу сформулировать требования, изложенные автором на картинке. потому что не знаю, насколько будут адекватны вопросу мысли, приходящие в голову очень далёкому от этой предметной области человеку типа меня. типа: «слегка смещённый вправо прямоугольник, разделённый по середине вертикально, в правой части поделённый горизонтально ещё на три неравные части». предложенный вами вариант, как вы можете убедиться сами, давным-давно реализован. и вопросы, и ответы, а даже комментарии нельзя отправить, если текст в них содержит меньше стольки-то букв.

Comment: @Sevastopol', вот вы явно даже не проверили. 1. «Минимальная длина заголовка 15 символов.»; «Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов». 2. при нажатии на кнопку «задать вопрос» всплывает «окно» в котором «грамотно, понятно и доступно» всё изложено. но если у вас есть предложения по поводу текста в этом окне, изложите его на мете, пожалуйста. 3. я пытаюсь донести до вас мысль, что тривиальные улучшения, о которых вы говорите, уже много-много лет как созданы.

Comment: @Sevastopol', так вы изложили свои предложения на мете? кроме предложения по поводу увеличения требования минимальной длины сообщения: думаю, его не стоит излагать, так как оно уже [изложено и обсуждено](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10504/298597) задолго до возникновения данного сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью грида:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "div-1 div-1 div-2"  
                       "div-1 div-1 div-3"
                       "div-1 div-1 div-4";
}

.container div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div-1 {
  grid-area: div-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-1">1</div>
  <div class="div-2">2</div>
  <div class="div-3">3</div>
  <div class="div-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: По моему я старею) Обогнали уже второй раз! И в задании колонки были одинаковой ширины) Так что 3 колонки это лишнее.

Comment: Это я так на ходу осваиваю гриды :)

Comment: Тоже самое) Куда же без бесплатной практики))

Answer (score 3):

Пока писал ответ, уже опередили, но вот мой вариант.

```css
.grid
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  
  background-color: #000;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.grid__item
{
  background-color: #FFF;
  min-height: 70px;
}
.grid__item--one
{
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--one">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--two">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--three">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--four">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сделал нормальные бордеры.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен( Обидно даже было)

Comment: Да не в репутации же дело)